# VSCode does not show errors in C/C++ before saving

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

VSCode won't show me error in C++ unless I save the file or do Command Pallete -> C/C++: Run Code Analysis on Active File.
It works properly in JS and Python, so I am 100% sure that it is a language-specific problem.

For example in Python/JS
[Shows me error immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNTun.png)

in C/C++
[Error does not show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coF7B.png)

[Error shows up only after I save/run code analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxS7l.png)

I turned error squiggles on and checked IntelliSense settings more than 100 times.

Comment: Check your c_cpp_properties.json which configures the Intellisense.

Comment: @drescherjm which property should i check?

Answer (score 0):

this question is old, but I am answering this question because I had wasted a lot of time for this annoying enviroment setup.

[C/C++ extension configuration change how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5oPS.png)

you need to toggle the setting, "Inteli Sense Engine" to

Tag Parser -> default

then the compiler warning alert will be shown as red squiggles.